# Searchkit deselect with group by option and how to save the sorting

Tags: searchkit

I have two questions:
How can I save the sorting of the results in a Searchkit search so that, for example, used in a dashlet, it always shows the most recently changed contacts at the top?
and
If I have created a search with several tags and then display the tags in the results, it makes sense to group them according to the display names. But when I want to select individual contacts, it always selects all of them. How can I solve this?
Thanks for the help!

About the second question:
I recorded a video for you.

https://speicher.dienstleistungskombinat.de/s/E2bystCZt6f32br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings for your SearchDisplay, near the top of the page, you can set Sort by Modified Date (even if Modified Date isn't a column in your Display).

I'm not quite sure what you are asking in your second question, could you perhaps post some screenshots of your search and a description of what you want the result to look like?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had passed the composed search to the form builder and not created a table. Thanks for the tip.

About the second question:
I recorded a video for you.

https://speicher.dienstleistungskombinat.de/s/E2bystCZt6f32br

Comment: I see what you mean. That looks like a bug to me, you should report it at https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

Comment: But that said, if you change Group by to Contact ID instead, it works as expected.

Comment: By they way, for your bug report, it's nothing specific to tags at all, it's just whenever you use Group by Display Name.

Comment: Wow, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To the 2nd part of your question, I believe you hit a bug. Please see this fix: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/27123